# APEX Select List based on query

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

APEX 4.2. I have Select List on form, based on query:

```
SELECT empno || ' ' || ename AS d, empno AS r
  FROM emp
```

When select list expanded there two concatenated fields displayed.

[image: when expanded]

But when some value selected and list collapsed I need only Ename displayed on form. So I need only JONES on pic 2 without number. Of course, return value must be empno anyway.

[image: when already selected]

[**EDIT**] I mean I need both Empno and Ename displayed when Select List opened, only Ename displayed when it collapsed and always Empno returned.

Comment: Do you want the empno displayed in the LOV when it is open, or just the name?  If not then obviously the LOV should be `SELECT ename AS d, empno AS r FROM emp`.  But to have the empno displayed when the list is open but not when it is closed is not simple.

Comment: Both empno and ename displayed when opened, only ename displayed when collapsed and always empno returned.

Comment: The trouble is, HTML selects don't work that way.  So you would need to find or create a plug-in item type that does, or write some fancy Javascript to manipulate what is being displayed when the list is open and when it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another textfield to catch the name and place it over the select list.so every time you select an item, the value displayed is controlled in a separate container. You can try it by doing this:

- > Aside from the SELECT LIST ITEM you have created. Add another TEXTFIELD.
- > Then on the Main Page under **Javascript > Execute when Page Loads**

Paste this code:

```
$('#P5_SELECT_CONTAINER div:nth-child(2)' ).append($('#P5_TEXT'));
var s_width = Number($('#P5_SELECT').css("width").replace("px",""));
$('#P5_TEXT').css({"width":(s_width-22)+"px","position":"relative","right":s_width+"px","pointer-events":"none"});
```

But first youll be needing the name/id of your select list and the textfield you created. For this code,

**select list id = P5_SELECT**

**textfield id =  P5_TEXT**

Just replace them(selectlist and textfield id) with what you already have.
Then create a dynamic action

> - **EVENT = Change**
> - **SELECTION TYPE = ITEM**
> - **ITEM = P5_SELECT**  (or in your case Name of your SELECT LIST)
> - **ACTION = EXECUTE JAVASCRIPT**

then paste this code

```
var sel = $('#P5_SELECT option:selected').text();
var substr_sel = sel.substr(sel.indexOf('-')+1).trim();
$s('P5_TEXT', substr_sel);
console.log($v('P5_TEXT')); -- just to check if return is correct.
```

> NOTE:just play with the width so that only the up/down arrow of the select list is displayed.

Hope this Helps